# "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lscala.Tuple2; cannot be cast to scala.Tuple2 in Spark MLlib LDA

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, lda

I'm using Spark 1.3.0 (Scala 2.10.X) MLlib LDA algorithm with Spark Java API. I have the following issue when I try to read the document-topic distribution from LDA model during runtime.

"main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lscala.Tuple2; cannot be cast to scala.Tuple2

I have given the relevant code below:

```
DistributedLDAModel ldaModel = new LDA().setK(3).run(corpus);
RDD<Tuple2<Object, Vector>> topicDist = ldaModel.topicDistributions();
```

How do I read or display the content (documents and their topic distribution) in "topicDist" in JavaRDD?

Comment: Seems like the required type is `Tuple2[]` array, but you give a standard type.

Comment: @MouseEvent: the other way around, actually :).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and I have given it below:

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Vector>> topicDist = ldaModel.topicDistributions().toJavaRDD();

List<Tuple2<Object, Vector>> list = topicDist.collect();
```